# Should I inform about an updated CV post deadline? (CS PhD USA)

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, united-states, computer-science, cv

**Background:** CS Undergrad applying to CS PhD Programs, USA.

(Assuming) I have a paper A in review at a Journal B, and I get the acceptance for the same 2 months post the deadline of applying.

**Question:**

1. Should I send the places I applied an e-mail saying that the paper which was in review (and mentioned in my SOP/LOR/CV) got accepted?
2. Does it have any effect on their decision?

Comment: If it is April and you are not on a waitlist, at an American university it is probably too late.

Comment: @Aymuos Are you waiting for a decision now? Or is this for next cycle?

Comment: This is for the next cycle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I send the places I applied an e-mail saying that the paper which was in review (and mentioned in my SOP/LOR/CV) got accepted?

No. Your CV/application is a snapshot in time, institutes likely won't update your CV/application, and they don't need such an additional burden. (Especially after two months, institutes are likely nearing or have made decisions.)

> Does it have any effect on their decision?

It would improve your CV/application, equally it may annoy the institutes: It may have a positive or negative impact.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i wanted to know!